# How i can edit message with button?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to do button, that editing message, but this button doesn't work.

```py
class Buttons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout=180):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
    @discord.ui.button(label="Button",style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def blurple_button(self,button:discord.ui.Button,interaction:discord.Interaction):
        button.style=discord.ButtonStyle.green
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="This is an edited button response!")

class test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("This message has buttons!",view=Buttons())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback's arguments are the wrong way around. The first one is supposed to be the `Interaction`, and the second the `Button`.

Your error message should also tell you this, though. You may not have configured logging properly.